# inserting data from one table to another sql using loop or array

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert data from one table into another (from table [PPRS] to table [Verify]) where the Caption in PPRS is the same as in table [Master]. Someone suggested i use a loop or array to insert the data instead of hard coding it, so ive tried a loop first

here's my code :

```
Declare @counter int 
declare @total int
set @counter = 0
SELECT @total =  Count(*) FROM PPRS

while @counter <= @total
    begin 
        set @counter += 1
        insert into [Verify]
        select [Task_ID],
        [Project_StartDate] ,
        [PPR_Caption],
        [Date] 
        FROM PPRS
        where [PPR_Caption] in (SELECT [Caption] from MasterRecords)

    end
```

however it says (0 rows inserted)

sample data:
Task_ID  PPR_Caption                               Project_StartDate User
17288    WC - Youth Environmental Services (12/15) 30/09/2018      Grace Modubu

Comment: Insert should be Enough for your Requirement, No need for loop

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. It doesn't need loops to insert data. All you need is a *single* `INSERT .. SELECT`. If that loop worked it would result in duplicate entries, since it always executes the *same* query. BTW if you want to retrieve the number of rows inserted use `@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: `0 rows inserted` means the `INSERT` statement run but no matching records were found. You should probably post the schema and test data for both tables. What happens if you just run the `SELECT` part of the query, do you get any results?

Answer (score 1):

This would insert all the records from PPRS where caption is in MasterRecords. No Need for Loop

```
insert into [Verify] 
select [Task_ID], [Project_StartDate] , [PPR_Caption], [Date] 
FROM PPRS 
where [PPR_Caption] in (SELECT [Caption] from MasterRecords);
```

Comment: the reason why i thought i should use a loop/array is because i have a web page where users upload data to [PPRS] table using excel spreadsheet and i want to use that data in a stored procedure . so that's why i want the data thats uploaded to [PPRS] table be inserted into [Verify] table

Comment: If you want all the data which is in PPRS Table to be inserted then this Query is Enough. If you want to Insert only Data which are not Available in Verify Table but are in PPRS Table then a Different Query would be needed, Please Clarify Your Requirement with Table Structure and Example Input Output